# Three.js: Uniforms value not updating

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader, tween.js

I'm using Tween.js to animate the uniforms value of a shader upon clicking a button. Here is what I have:

```
Shader.uniforms.threshold.needsUpdate = true;

function fadeIn() {
  new TWEEN.Tween( Shader.uniforms.threshold )
  .to( { value : 0.6 }, 100 )
  .start();
}

function fadeOut() {
  new TWEEN.Tween( Shader.uniforms.threshold )
  .to( { value : 2 }, 100 )
  .start();
}

document.getElementById("FadeIn").onclick = function() {
   fadeIn();
}

document.getElementById("FadeOut").onclick = function() {
   fadeOut();
}
```

The above does not work. When I try refreshing the page, the value does change but the button click does nothing. Does anyone know the mistake in my implementation? Can Tween.js be used like this or is there a better method? Thanks.

Comment: take a look at `onUpdate` on the [tween.js page](https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/).

Comment: Yes, the the values are shown to be changing correctly, but it isn't actually being rendered? Do you know why?

Comment: hard to tell without seeing more of your code

Comment: Ok I got it working by changing the value of individual objects instead of the shader itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's how I got it working. It seems changing the value of the "Shader" itself is the cause. The above works when I change the uniforms value of the individual objects. So instead of `Shader.uniforms.threshold`, I did this:

`myObject.material.uniforms.threshold`, which works.